# $G$ is an infinite group and $G/Z(G)$ is finite. Show that every conjugacy class is finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$G$ is an infinite group and $G/Z(G)$ is finite.

Need to show that every conjugacy class is finite.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: $G/Z(G) \cong \operatorname{Inn}(G)$.

Answer (score 2):

Hints: let $g \in G$, then use the orbit-stabilizer theorem applied to $G$ acting on its elements by conjugation to show that the order of the conjugacy class is $|Cl_G(g)|= index[G:C_G(g)]$, where $C_G(g)=\{x \in G : xg=gx\}$, the so-called centralizer of $g$. Now observe that $Z(G) \subseteq C_G(g)$ for any $g \in G$.